# openining xterm and sending commands from xinitrc

Tags: x11, xdotool

In my xinitrc file, how can I execute commands after the xterm has opened so that I can use xdotool to move the mouse etc ?

```
    xterm -geometry 132x45+0+0
    xdotool windowfocus
    xdotool mousemove 100 100
    xdotool click 1
```

In this example, the xdotool command only execute when xterm quits, I can't add & to the command line for xterm as it will not remain open ?

Answer (score 0):

`.xinitrc` is a shell script and usually exits with an `exec` to start your the last application or window manager. When this last application quits, the X session finishes.

Any application started before reaching the end of the script must be stated asynchronously by using a trailing `&`.

You could end the script with a *sleep forever* statement (for example [this one](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/42901/how-to-do-nothing-forever-in-an-elegant-way#42905)) to keep the X session open.

Your overall plan is error prone, however, as there is no guarantee that Xterm will be fully stated before the ancillary operations are executed.